# Long execution time for _abpZeroDbMigrator.CreateOrMigrateForTenant(tenant) in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, database-migration, abp, ef-core-2.1

Title: Long execution time for _abpZeroDbMigrator.CreateOrMigrateForTenant(tenant) in ASP.NET Core application

Question Body:
I'm encountering a significant delay in the execution of `_abpZeroDbMigrator.CreateOrMigrateForTenant(tenant)` within my ASP.NET Core application. The method is responsible for creating or migrating the database for a specific tenant. However, it is taking more than 15 minutes to complete, which is causing performance issues in my application. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to improve the execution time.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

1. The code where `_abpZeroDbMigrator.CreateOrMigrateForTenant(tenant)` is called:

   ```cs
   using (CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant))
   {
       // Other code...

       await _abpZeroDbMigrator.CreateOrMigrateForTenant(tenant);

       // Other code...
   }
   ```
2. Additional information about the environment and configuration:

- ASP.NET Core version: [e.g., 3.1]
- Database provider: [e.g., PostgreSQL]
- Number of tenants: [e.g., 100]
- Database size per tenant: [e.g., approximately 1 GB]
- Hardware specifications: [e.g., CPU, RAM]
- Any relevant database configuration settings or optimizations already applied.

I have already verified that the delay is not caused by network latency or database server performance. The issue seems to be specific to the `_abpZeroDbMigrator.CreateOrMigrateForTenant` method itself. Are there any strategies or optimizations that can be applied to reduce the execution time?

I appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance.